# Ninject.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net Produces Incorrect Output for Class/Method Name

Tags: c#, log4net, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) 3.0.1.10 for dependency injection and want to use [Ninject.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging) 3.0.1.0 for [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) 1.2.11 logging. However, I'm getting different output in my log files when using the extension rather than log4net directly. I want the output to contain the name of the class/method that does the logging, as follows in my app.config:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="MyConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="MyConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %C{1}.%M():%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

I've made a sample project to demonstrate the problem I'm seeing as follows:

```
public class LoggingWithLog4Net
{
    private readonly ILog log;

    public LoggingWithLog4Net(ILog log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        log.Debug(message);
    }
}

public class LoggingWithNinject
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public LoggingWithNinject(ILogger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        log.Debug(message);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        NinjectSettings settings = new NinjectSettings()
        {
            LoadExtensions = false
        };

        using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, new Log4NetModule()))
        {
            kernel.Bind<ILog>()
                .ToConstant(LogManager.GetLogger("*"));

            LoggingWithLog4Net l4n = kernel.Get<LoggingWithLog4Net>();
            LoggingWithNinject ninject = kernel.Get<LoggingWithNinject>();

            l4n.LogMessage("log4net message");
            ninject.LogMessage("ninject message");
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following output (note the incorrect class/method name in the Ninject version):

```
2012-06-21 08:25:19,000 DEBUG LoggingWithLog4Net.LogMessage():21 - log4net message
2012-06-21 08:25:19,015 DEBUG Log4NetLogger.Debug():98 - ninject message
```

I would expect the second line to have `LoggingWithNinject.LogMessage():21` as the source class/method but instead the Ninject `Log4NetLogger` is used as the source. How can I get the source to be properly identified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what I want isn't possible. The `%C{1}.%M():%L` part of the configuration causes log4net to print the location information of the calling class. In the log4net version, you call `Log4NetLogger` and it passes your call onto log4net. This means the source will always be `Log4NetLogger`.

As a compromise, I've used the following:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %c - %m%n" />
```

This loses the method name and line number of the call, but you do get the correct class name when using the Ninject extension because loggers are always requested by `Type` which default to the full namespace/name combo of the class.

The other alternative is to inject `log4net.ILog` directly and stop using the Ninject extension.

Comment: I'm having exactly this problem at the moment.  This seems like a huge hole in the functionality of Ninject.Extensions.Logging.  It seems to boil down to, you can have dependency injection using the framework and ILogger interface or the correct stacktrace/class name etc and use the ILog interface.  Is that right or am I missing something?